# WMI query local administrators including group members

Tags: wmi, wmic

I know how to fetch a list of local administrators on a remote machine via WMI:

```
wmic /Node:"ComputerName" path win32_groupuser where (groupcomponent="win32_group.name=\"administrators\",domain=\"Computername\"")
```

This will return users and groups:

```
GroupComponent                                          PartComponent
win32_group.domain="Computername",name="administrators"  \\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="Computername",Name="Administrator"
win32_group.domain="Computername",name="administrators"  \\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="MYDOMAIN",Name="Domain Admins"
win32_group.domain="Computername",name="administrators"  \\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="MYDOMAIN",Name="SomeOtherGroup"
win32_group.domain="Computername",name="administrators"  \\Computername\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="MYDOMAIN",Name="MyUser"
```

However, if a user is a member of `SomeOtherGroup` above, I need to know that he is a member - and therefore a local admin. So, I need to expand (likely recursively) all group members.

Is there a WMI query that can self-join on `win32_group`, expanding all usernames of all groups that are local admins?

Comment: I don't believe there is, so you probably need to enumerate the members of the groups found in the first search, and then join the results yourself. But someone else may have a different idea.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pessimistic myself. All I really want is `bool IsUserLocalAdmin(string username)` LOL